# Updating a date in a column of one table based on the earliest date from another column in a different table

Tags: sql-server

I have looked on this site and cannot quite find an example of this situation.

I have two tables 'matters' and 'time'. I want to set the date column in the matter table to equal the earliest date from the column in the time table (only where the date is greater in the matter table compared to the time table). The unique identifier between the two tables is the matter column. I cannot use an aggregate in the WHERE or ON clause to find the earliest (MIN) date and am struggling to find a way around this.

Here is what I have so far:

```
UPDATE matter
SET mopendt = 
(SELECT MIN(tworkdt)
FROM matter
JOIN timecard
ON mmatter = tmatter
WHERE mopendt > MIN(tworkdt))
```

Let me know if you need anymore information.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need & although your field names were not entirely clear I think you'll see the pattern to follow:

```
  UPDATE matter 
  SET mopendt = tmin.tworkdt
    FROM matter
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT tmatter, MIN(tworkdt) as tworkdt
        FROM timecard
        GROUP BY tmatter) AS tmin 
    ON matter.mmatter = tmin.tmatter;
```

If you only want to update a specific record then add a WHERE clause (at the end).
The subquery correlates, so you shouldn't need to add the filter to the inner query.
Otherwise you will be setting the min time for *all* the records all the time, which could get costly for a reasonable tablesize (and is normally unecessary unless you are doing bulk uploads)